# Identical Processor - Live Migration Error

Tags: virtualization, hyper-v, bios, hypervisor, hyperthreading

I have production problem thats why Im asking for fast help :/

Environment 
2 new HyperV Host with Windows 2016 in Failover Cluster
Both with CPU:
Intel® Xeon® Silver 4116 Processor 2.10 Ghz

Live migration VM started on node 1 to node 2 success with back migration.
Live migration VM started on node 2 to node 1 - error - incompatible CPU processors error.
During service window we shutdown VMs and enabled checkbox:
Migrate to different cpu version on HyperV settings - not help :/

Service window end and we have no idea what now.
1st node was prepared in BIOS by me.
2nd node was prepared in BIOS by my friend

And now we need to find what is the difference between nodes configuration....

Probably we could ask for service window and reset factory BIOS to default settings but I do not want do this - its next LONG service window - we dont have much time now...

How to check incompatible CPU feature in cmd / powerhell ( or any other tool) without checking every option in BIOS ???

In another word - how to find difference between configuration.

Comment: At the very worst, you could shut the VM's down and perform a Quick Migration, which would be a temporary workaround to this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by upgrade both servers to newest BIOS version.

Answer (score 0):

You have two identical CPU, but they have any firmware? With the same version?

This can be a potential cause, if one have a more recent firmware, you can transfert to it, but not from it.

Comment: It aslo include the motherboard  firmware version, wich can alter the interaction between the OS and the CPU.

Comment: Motherboard firmware, CPU microcode, BIOS settings, everything.

Comment: Used coreinfo from sysinternals and compared. Have only difference with: Approximate Cross-NUMA Node Access Cost (relative to fastest):
00  01
00: 1.1 1.0
01: 1.6 2.2